# How to build react js with only one chunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a react js project and im actually dont know how to set webpack settings. After i run "npm run build" i get 10 js files names 1.js 2.js 3.js with main.js. I dont know how to bundle them. I searched some questions but couldnt solve it. Its not my first project in react but i didnt try to
build with webpack before. Thanks for helps.

My webpack.prod.js ;

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ResourceManifestPlugin = require('webpack-fivem-manifest');

module.exports = require('./webpack.common')({
  mode: 'production',

  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [path.join(process.cwd(), 'src/app.js')],

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),
    new ResourceManifestPlugin(),
  ],

  performance: {
    assetFilter: assetFilename =>
      !/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename),
  },
});
```

My webpack.common.js :

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = options => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'html'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false,
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: `ifdef-loader`,
            options: {
              DEBUG: options.mode !== 'production',
              version: 3,
              'ifdef-verbose': true, // add this for verbose output
              'ifdef-triple-slash': true, // add this to use double slash comment instead of default triple slash
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In a typical React application, the build process usually involves generating multiple chunks to optimize code splitting and enable more efficient loading of resources. However, if you specifically want to build your React app into a single chunk (a single JavaScript file), you can configure your bundler accordingly.

1. Eject from Create React App:
   Ejecting allows you to customize the build configuration. Keep in mind that ejecting is a one-way operation, so make sure you want to do this before proceeding.

> npm run eject

2.Edit webpack.config.js:
After ejecting, you will find a config folder in your project root. Open config/webpack.config.js and locate the output section. Modify the filename property to force a single chunk:

> output: {   // ...   filename like,: 'static/js/bundle.js',   // ... },

3.Build the app:
Now you can build your React app, and it should generate only one JavaScript chunk.

> npm run build

Also please Keep in mind that creating a single chunk might negatively impact performance, especially for larger applications. Code splitting and generating multiple chunks can lead to faster initial page loads and better caching in subsequent visits. Before opting for a single chunk, consider the implications on performance and user experience.